# "No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected" after update to 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning, ios4

I updated my iPhone to the new OS 4.0 and went to build my iPhone app and everything built ok, but the message I got at the end was "No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected". Looking at the Xcode organiser, it shows my connected device with an amber icon next to it, and all my provisioning profiles show up as "Installed" but also with an amber icon.

Is there something I need to do to make the existing provisioning profiles work since updating to OS 4.0?

I have XCode 3.1.3, and 10.5.8 OS. I can not install XCode 3.2.3, because for that I would need 10.6.2 OS which I do not have.

So, how do I continue developing and debugging as I used to before I said "yes" to the update dialog on my iPhone, without buying a new OS or new iPhone?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT1: 
I do not want to develop for iOS 4.0.

Comment: "I do not want to develop for iOS 4.0." <- maybe google can help: http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=how+to+downgrade+ioS+4+&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGLL_enHK368HK368&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install Xcode 3.2.3 if you have a device with iOS4, whether you want to use iOS4 features or not.

Apple don't support downgrading your phone to earlier version of the OS, though there are ways of doing it. Your only "official" option is to move to Snow Leopard I'm afraid. (Though it's worth doing anyway)

Answer (score 3):

They're all wrong.

All you *need* is `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0 (8A293)` (it might be called just "4.0" in future releases). Grab it from a computer with 4.0 installed, or, or extract it from the install package (Pacifist, or lsbom/cpio/ditto), or whatever.

GDB doesn't like being run without symbols though, so also grab a copy of `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk` (**EDIT:** I haven't tried this either, but it ought to work provided the object file format hasn't changed much). This will also let you *attempt* to compile for 4.0, but I haven't checked if it works (I don't know if 3.1.3's GCC supports "blocks").

**EDIT:** All that said, it's going to be easier if you just bite the bullet and upgrade. You need to compile against 4.0 if you want certain features like having your app backgrounded instead of killed (-[UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:]).

Comment: Tricks like this certainly work for minor updates, though I'd be hesitant to use it as anything but a short-term stop-gap for a major release (such as iOS4).

Comment: I'm more worried about using bits of a Snow Leopard SDK on Leopard. It worked for me though, for the week or two before I upgraded to SL.

Comment: For every problem there's a hack, but that doesn't mean we are wrong by saying it's not possible. Officially you can't deploy on an iOS4 device when you're running Xcode 3.1 / SDK 3.1. It's a lot safer to upgrade to Snow Leopard than it is to hack your installation like this.

Comment: "Safer" for what? It doesn't affect your 3.1.3 SDK; it lets you install the built-against-3.1.3 app on your 4.0 phone. It's not really even a hack.

Answer (score 2):

XCode 3.2.3 is required to develop iOS 4 apps.

Comment: I do not want to develop for iOS 4.0.

Comment: @Bojan - all new iPhones are being sold with iOS 4.0 and I would expect that most people will upgrade their phones (if only inadvertently, like you did) so you're going to have to upgrade at some point.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to develop for iOS 4, you should be running Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard), and you have to install the iOS 4 SDK.

Comment: I do not want to develop for iOS 4.0.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you want to debug on a device running iOS4, you'll need Snow Leopard and the iOS 4 SDK

Comment: So, for simple mistake of accepting 4.0 update on my phone, now I need to buy a new operating system?

Comment: Indeed. Why is that so bad? Upgrading to Snow Leopard is a smart thing to do (and not expensive)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have iTunes 9.2 if you are connecting an iOS4 device. The device won't be detected even in xcode if its os is 4.0 and you are still using an older version of iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading phone to iOS 4.2
I had to:

- upgrade XCode to 3.2.5
- reboot phone with XCode not running, as described above.
- bring up XCode, Window, Organizer, and when in the view for

  - Jim'sPhone, Summary (I think) or
  - Provisioning Profiles or something, Sorry-- I forget which...

Given the warning similar to "XCode doesn't have debugging information for this version of iOS"

==> select "Collect"

Keep Organizer in view to see progress... it takes a minute or two. After I did that,
I was able to build and install/debug.

Answer (score 0):

A simple tip: force removal of device with right-click on the device where the amber dot is ("Remove from Organzer"). Reconnect again and the device should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Make sure your XCode is up-to-date.
2. Reboot your iOS.

For some reason updating the OS makes it confused as to its provisioning profile until it it reboots.